# GraphQL field resolver needs contextual information

Tags: api, graphql, microservices, aws-appsync

Maybe my terminology is not accurate. I'm using AWS AppSync. My schema:

```
type Book {
  title: String
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  name: String
}

type Query {
  getBook(title:String!): Book
}
```

The resolver for `getBook` returns an object shaped as:

```
{
  title: <string>
  authorId: <number>
}
```

Where `authorId` is always returned.

What I'd like to do is specify a resolver for the field `Book.author` that will receive `authorId` and fetch that object from its own data store. Is this possible?

If what I'm trying to do is not possible, what is the proper way of doing this, where one data store is a table with two columns - `{ title, authorId }`, and a separate store has a table with a list of authors, where the primary key is a column `authorId`. Since these are two different services, I can't just *join* the two like a SQL query.

Comment: The resolver functions are code, and essentially anything is possible.  Making two calls and reshaping the data to meet the API format you're planning to expose seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `authorId` is returned from the `getBook` resolver, it will be accessible via `$ctx.source.authorId` when resolving `Book.author`.

I reproduced your API with local resolvers using your schema:

`Query.getBook` request mapping template:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "payload": {
        "title": "$context.arguments.title",
        "authorId": "2" ## returned in addition to other fields. It will be used by Book.author resolver.
    }
}
```

`Query.getBook` response mapping template:

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

`Book.author` request mapping template:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "payload": {
        "name": "author name with authorId: $context.source.authorId"
    }
}
```

`Book.author` response mapping template:

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

The following query:

```
query {
  getBook(title:"AWS AppSync") {
    title 
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

will yield the results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getBook": {
      "title": "AWS AppSync",
      "author": {
        "name": "author name with authorId: 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to have `bookID` as parent's ID inside `Author`:

```
type Author {
    # parent's id
    bookID: ID!
    # author id
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: Author!
}
```

When `Create Resource`, just make:
 - `Book.id` as `primary key` of `BookTable`
 - `Author.bookID` as `primary key` and `Author.id` as `sort key` of
   `AuthorTable`

[image]

You also need to attach resolver for `Book.author` using `$ctx.source.id`

[image]

After you attach `Book.author` resolver, you are good to go. You can get result something like below:

```
getBook(title: "xx") {
  id
  title
  author {
    id
    name
  }
}
```